# How to add a fragment inside a table row programmatically?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I can achieve this with this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/startoverviewfragmentLayoutId" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.xxxx.xxx.MyMediaPlayer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

But how can i do it with java code? I tried this:

```
    MyMediaPlayer mpv = new MyMediaPlayer(); //Fragment
    TableRow tt = (TableRow)myView.findViewById(R.id.tableRow1); 
    tt.addView(mpv);
```

But since a fragment isnt a view this wont work. So how should i do?

Comment: simply use a FragmentManager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For backward compatibly replace your

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="com.xxxx.xxx.MyMediaPlayer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

with

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</FrameLayout>
```

in your activity use this code

```
MyMediaPlayer myf = new MyMediaPlayer();

FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.fragment1, myf);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks, this saved me so much time :). Ohh, what if i completly delete the <fragment> tag, than put it directly in the row, i.e. transaction.add(R.id.tableRow1, myf);  .... Do you still recommend me to create a FrameLayout (in code, i want to do most of the layout in java) to put the fragment in?

Comment: I have not tried that but I think, If you don't need the extra container, you can skip it. If you can please comment back so I know. Thanks!